# Regex not working for following pattern

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to figure out a regex which matches the following conditions in a query parameter. I need to find if the  text has an `and` or `or` operator passed in the query parameters. I can have a URI like `http:$URL/$RESOURCE?$filter="firstName eq 'John' and tenantId eq '32323232'"&$order="asc.`

Text 1: `firstName eq 'John' and tenantId eq '32323232'`
Text 2: `firstName like 'J%' or companyName eq 'IBM'`
Text 3: `companyName like 'John and Sons'`

While the following regex pattern does work for Text 1 and Text 2, however I need a way to filter out Text 3, since the and here comes inside a value. Values shall always be in quotes, so any `and` or `or` values in quotes should be ingored by regex. Any help to filter out cases like Text 3 shall be appreciated. Thanks

```
public static boolean hasANDorORoperator(String filter) {
    return filter.matches("^(.*?)\\s+(?i)(or|and)\\s+(.*?)$");
}
```

Comment: tenantId is just a key of a key-value pair.

Comment: @Flimzy: Doesnt really matter, does it?

Comment: @Daemon: That's a modifier that is only applied to that capturing group.

Comment: Are you expecting escaped quotes in your texts?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  With regex questions, it is usually helpful (necessary) to identify which language are you embedding your regex in?  It looks like Java or C# to my eyes, but they're unskilled in both languages.

Comment: I think I see the reason for my confusion: Your URL is improperly formatted; it contains spaces. I didn't realize the tenantId was supposed to be part of your URL string.

Comment: @Flimzy: I must have missed that when editing, thanks for correcting it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(and|or)(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)
```

will only match `and` or `or` if an even number of quotes follow. So if you're inside a string, that condition is not met and the match fails.

[See it on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/jC9hT8).

**Explanation:**

```
(and|or)  # Match and/or.
(?=       # only if the following can be matched here:
 (?:      # Start of non-capturing group:
  [^']*'  # Match any number of non-quote characters plus a quote
  [^']*'  # twice in a row.
 )*       # Repeat any number of times, including zero.
 [^']*    # Match any remaining non-quote characters
 $        # until the end of the string.
)         # End of lookahead assertion.
```

Comment: +1 you beat me to it! Although I prefer `{2}` to repeating the non-quote/quote sequence

Comment: +1 Thanks for the link, very useful online regex checking tool.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd pull out all of the strings first, like in Text 3's example. I'd first filter out 'John and Sons'.

Then, you'd only be left with the raw commands which you could match with the (.*)\s+(and|or)\s+(.*) regular expression.

Then you wouldn't have to deal with the resulting complicated regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^((.*)('[^']')?)*(and|or)[^']*$/i
```

should do the trick. I'm capturing anything inside parantheses before matching the end/or, so it shouldn't be a possible match for the end/or anymore. Because most regexp engines backtrack to match later capturing groups, I included the `no '` at the end.

Comment: Single quotes `'`, not double quotes `"`.